how to print all variables?
In the following module, I'm able to print reassigned variables by means of sequence. Now I want to print all variables and their values that are defined in calculation. Is there any way to do this ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {
  \keyval_parse:NNn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n \xcn_eqdef_def:nn {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{O{15}m}
 {
  %\tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
  \fpeval{round( \tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#2_tl }, #1) }
 }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usevar}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n
 {
  \msg_error:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value } {#1}
 }
\msg_new:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value }
 { Missing~value~for~the~variable~#1 }

\seq_new:N \g_tmp_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_def:nn
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   {
    %\msg_warning:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist } {#1}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmp_seq {#1}
   }
   {
    \tl_new:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   }
  \tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } {#2} 
 }
\newcommand\ReassignedVar{\seq_use:Nn \g_tmp_seq {,\ ~}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][1.5pt]{\genfrac{}{}{.6pt}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{\dimexpr -3pt-#1}{$#3$}}}

\begin{document}

\eqdef{M=400,N=1000,h=500,b=400,ea=20,as=40,ho=\?{h}-\?{as},fc=14.3,x=50}

$e_0=M/N=\?{M}/\?{N}=\eqdef{eo=\?{M}/\?{N}}\?{eo}\unit{m}
=\eqdef{eo=\?{eo}*1000}\qty{\?{eo}}{mm}$ 

$ x=\myfrac{N}{\alpha_1 f_c b}
=\myfrac{\?{N}\times10^3}{1\times14.3\times400}
=\eqdef{x=\?{N}*1000/\?{fc}/\?{b}}\?[2]{x}\unit{mm}
\begin{aligned}
&<\xi_b h_0=\eqdef{xb=0.518*\?{ho}}\?{xb}\unit{mm} \\
&>2a_s{'}=\eqdef{temp=2*\?{as}}\?{temp}\unit{mm}
\end{aligned}
$

\vskip9pt
\noindent\dotfill

All Variable:%M=400, N=2000, ...

Reassigned Variable: \ReassignedVar

\end{document}



you don't seem to be saving the variables into any kind of organised data structure? so I don't see how you can pull them all back unless you keep track of them or change the way you're structuring the data as you save it. if you used a property list or something rather than token lists, you could iterate over that list to pick everything up. or you could use something to track the token lists e.g. a sequence or whatever.

thanks a lot. I'll try to do it.

just create a new sequence to track all variable
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {
  \keyval_parse:NNn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n \xcn_eqdef_def:nn {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{O{15}m}
 {
  %\tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
  \fpeval{round( \tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#2_tl }, #1) }
 }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usevar}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n
 {
  \msg_error:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value } {#1}
 }
\msg_new:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value }
 { Missing~value~for~the~variable~#1 }

\seq_new:N \g_tmp_seq
\seq_new:N \g_all_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_def:nn
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   {
    %\msg_warning:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist } {#1}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tmp_seq {#1}
   }
   {
    \tl_new:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   }
  \tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } {#2} 
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_all_seq { #1=\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{\fpeval{#2}} }
 }
\newcommand\ReassignedVar{\seq_use:Nn \g_tmp_seq {,\ ~}}
\newcommand\Allvar{\seq_use:Nn \g_all_seq {,\ ~}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][1.5pt]{\genfrac{}{}{.6pt}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{\dimexpr -3pt-#1}{$#3$}}}

\begin{document}

\eqdef{M=400,N=1000,h=500,b=400,ea=20,as=40,ho=\?{h}-\?{as},fc=14.3,x=50}

$e_0=M/N=\?{M}/\?{N}=\eqdef{eo=\?{M}/\?{N}}\?{eo}\unit{m}
=\eqdef{eo=\?{eo}*1000}\qty{\?{eo}}{mm}$ 

$ x=\myfrac{N}{\alpha_1 f_c b}
=\myfrac{\?{N}\times10^3}{1\times14.3\times400}
=\eqdef{x=\?{N}*1000/\?{fc}/\?{b}}\?[2]{x}\unit{mm}
\begin{aligned}
&<\xi_b h_0=\eqdef{xb=0.518*\?{ho}}\?{xb}\unit{mm} \\
&>2a_s{'}=\eqdef{temp=2*\?{as}}\?{temp}\unit{mm}
\end{aligned}
$

\vskip9pt
\noindent\dotfill

All Variable: \Allvar

Reassigned Variable: \ReassignedVar
\end{document}


